# unset somehow destroys all absolutely different sessions

Tags: php, session, unset

I have one serious problem.

There is a little PHP system, which contains admin panel and customer panel.
These panels **must be functioning independently from each other**.

For example - **if admin logs out, customer must stay inside, etc.**

There is my **logout.php** script (which is called by logout button javascript handler):

```
<?php
require_once("./setup/additional_functions.php");
require_once("./setup/mysql_settings.php");
session_start();

$functionName = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "functionName");

if($functionName == "logoutAdmin") {
   initiateLogout("um_status", "users_managers", "um_id", $_SESSION['admin_id'], "admin");
} else if($functionName == "logoutCustomer") {
   initiateLogout("customer_visit", "users_customers", "customer_id", $_SESSION['cust_id'], "../customer");
} else {
    echo "Unknown error!";
}
function initiateLogout($loginTime, $tableName, $id, $sessionName, $backPage) {
    $sqli = new sqlSettings();
    $sql = "SELECT ". $loginTime ." FROM ". $tableName ." WHERE ". $id ." = ". $sessionName;
    $result = $sqli->setConnection()->query($sql);
    $user = $result->fetch_array();
    $timestamp = $user[$loginTime] - 300;

    $sql = "UPDATE " .$tableName. " SET " .$loginTime ." = ". $timestamp. " WHERE " .$id ." = ". $sessionName;
    $result = $sqli->setConnection()->query($sql);

    $_SESSION = array();

    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 50000, '/');
    }

    unset($sessionName); 
    //redirect_to($backPage);
    echo "../" . $backPage;
}
```

?>

**Data inside $_SESSION['admin_id'] and $_SESSION['customer_id'] - absolutely different!** But anyway - when I hit button (for example) on admin side - customer also logs out!!! It shouldn't be like this.

How to avoid this? Will be very thankful for any help!!

Comment: You're logging them out both out with $_SESSION = array();

Comment: I commented line with  $_SESSION = array(); . It affects nothing. The same thing repeats.

Comment: Well, can anybody help me? I still need help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be setting $_SESSION to an empty array.

You need to be setting the respective $_SESSION key to null or insetting it.

For customers this would be `unset($_SESSION['cust_id'])` and for admin this would be `unset($_SESSION['admin_id'])`

Your current code destroys the whole session which logs both customer and admin accounts out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think my mistake was in testing whole system on my **local computer**. Cause if you do the same - session is being created **during one browser and one pc**. And it doesn't matter **by whom you're logged in**. After I placed my system **on remote server** and tested my old code **from different "points"** - everything works perfect.